# How to fetch parents based on their child's records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models like

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :posts
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company

    scope :notClosed, -> {where(closed: false)}
    scope :published, -> {where(published: true)}
end
```

I want to fetch companies which carries at least one post with matching post `scope`

Currently my queries is

```
Company.where(company_type: "Private").all
```

It's return all companies but how to modify this query for my needs.

Comment: _I want to fetch companies which carries at least one post_, actually, an INNER JOIN keyword would return the companies with posts associated, you can append a distinct statement to get non-repeated records. Can you explain further what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to fetch company which post record zero based on post `scope` like `notClosed` and `published` @SebastianPalma

Comment: So, try `Company.joins(:posts).distinct.merge(Post.notClosed)`.

Comment: Hey @SebastianPalma, maybe it's working see the query *`SELECT  DISTINCT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."company_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "companies"."company_type" = ? AND "posts"."closed" = ? AND "posts"."published" = ? LIMIT ?  [["company_type", "Private"], ["closed", "f"], ["published", "t"], ["LIMIT", 11]]`*, can you please suggest me about speed performance issue because my database is only posts over one million, I think you can post this as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
published_post_companies = Company.joins(:posts).distinct.merge(Post.published)
notClosed_post_companies = Company.joins(:posts).distinct.merge(Post.notClosed)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all Companies (once) with at least one post that's "not closed":

```
Company.includes(:posts).joins(:posts).where(company_type: "Private").merge(Post.notClosed)
```

Comment: It's execution time is to long

Comment: Do you have database indices on all the relevant columns, i. e. company.company_type, post,company_id, post.closed, post.published?

Answer (score -1):

The explicit Rails way: get the IDs of companies from the `Post` scope then query on those IDs:

```
Company.where(id: Post.published.pluck(:company_id).uniq)
```

Note, however, this might be expensive if you have a huge amount of posts. There could be a more efficient way using SQL.

Comment: My database is only posts over one million

Comment: `where(id: Post.published.select(:company_id))` would serve you better, that would do a subquery inside the database rather than pulling a bunch of data out of the database and then sending it back. It also neatly avoids duplicates that JOINs can introduce.

Comment: Hello Sir @muistooshort, I have several condition like `type: "private"`, `notClosed`, `published` & not `expired` how the query based on that condition, can you please suggest me.

Comment: @muistooshort TIL, ty for the comment.